# stock reduction with triggers on MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

[image: example image]

I have a problem when reducing the stock of goods, I want to reduce the stock of goods based on id_ barang and id_rak.

how to create two conditions on triggers based on id_barang and id_rak

My code

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE transfer SET qty_tf=qty_tf-NEW.qty_outbound
  WHERE id_rak=NEW.id_rak;
END
```

Comment: Please give an example of 'based on id_barang and id_rak' - i am unclear what your problem is given that an update in a trigger is no different to any other update.

Comment: I want to issue qty_tf stock based on id_ barang and id_rak.

example

qty_tf stock is 3, and I want to reduce the stock by 2

I want to reduce the stock qty_tf which has id_barang 15 and id_rak 1


sorry my language is not good

Comment: Your where statament just becomes where id_barang = 15 AND id_rak = 1 - I'm still not seeing your problem.

Comment: sql example

SELECT .......... FROM transfer WHERE id_barang = ... AND id_rak ....


what if triggered?

Comment: Not with you triggers don't fire on select statements - only on update/insert/delete.

Comment: Enter when I enter with the same id_rak, the other qty_tf decreases

example
id_barang 15 and id_rak 1

id_ barang 16 and id_rak_1

the value is the same as decreasing, which I input is the value of id_ barang 15 and id_rak 1